# How to run tslint continuously with webpack or vs code during development

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-code, tslint

When I was using gulp in an Angular 1.x project, I can use gulp to watch files changes and run eslint continuously.  In my Angular 2 project, I am using webpack and vs code, how do I make tslint continuously running?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
"watch:lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" -- --watch",
```

I haven't tried integrating tslint with vs code.  Can vs code give me constant feedback on the files that I am working on with tslint?  Any info is appreciated.

Comment: simply installing tslint plugin works on vscode.  still interested in how to do it with webpack or npm

Comment: I am interested in that if you are interested in [helping out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515582/how-do-i-get-tslint-to-watch-for-changes-in-a-specific-folder):

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not exactly what you're looking for, but `tslint-loader` might be useful

https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader

It poses a preLoader and check files before compilation.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For single execution

1. install gulp
2. run the command `gulp tslint`

Alternatively, This vscode extension would make your work much more easy

**[VS Code tslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint)**