# Is there a way to run a linter on a React project every time the code is saved?

Tags: reactjs

Rather simple question really.

I come from a background of VueJS, where this is all setup for the user automatically. I'd like my linter (tslint, if that matters) to just run automatically when any file is saved in the project, but all the resources I've found stop at adding a command to the package.json file. Having a separate command for the linter is great and all, but I want those lint warnings to come up in the terminal while the dev server is running.

Edit: Not a duplicate of "How do I get tslint to watch for changes in a specific folder?" as that does not address what I'm looking to do. I can see that I can have a file watcher run separately from the server, but I do not want that. I'd like running the server to start the linter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get tslint to watch for changes in a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515582/how-do-i-get-tslint-to-watch-for-changes-in-a-specific-folder)

Comment: I believe the implementation of typescript create-react-app integrates tslint into compilation. If nobody can give you a satisfactory answer, you might want to consider making a dummy cra project, ejecting it, and looking at all of the config files. One thing to note is that having the ts type checker, babel transpiler, and linter all in one process grinds compilation to a halt. I shaved my compilation time down to 30% (17 seconds -> 5ish) of what it used to be by having all 3 processes run separately

Comment: I have strong feeling that you better set up IDE you use instead of running linter as a watcher task in terminal.

Comment: @skyboyer Well I don't always use and IDE, so that's just silly advice. Development really should not be linked to using certain IDE's, as I should be able to quickly edit a file in vim and still get warnings, if need be.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'd like to configure eslint to work like this one from Vue CLI. Did you find some similar approach for React?

Comment: Nope. Gave up on that hope.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i was doing :

```
"watch": {
    "lint": "src/main.ts"
},
"scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint src/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "watch": "npm-watch"
},
```

for that you need npm-watch.  Here is a good explanation [How do I get tslint to watch for changes in a specific folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515582/how-do-i-get-tslint-to-watch-for-changes-in-a-specific-folder)

Hope it helps.

EDIT: I currently use VsCode and the TSLint plugin just shows everything on the IDE so i dont set it this way anymore

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for here. `watch` should be built into the running of the server, so that while the server is running, the linter runs as well. What you suggested is still separate from the running of the server, no?

Comment: Well if you look into the answer I linked he provides this tool https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar to be able to do what i understand is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can install vscode prettier [plugin](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#installation) for exactly this.

After installing it, open your vscode settings (user/workspace) and enable **[Format on save](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#format-on-save)** as it respects the setting. Plus you can do it on language basis.

You can then [configure your linters](https://prettier.io/docs/en/integrating-with-linters.html) (ESLint/TSLint) to work with prettier.

More info is available on prettier's github repo - https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode

Comment: Well I don't use VSCode, nor do I want something that will format. That's why I'm using TSLint, and not whatever that is.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to add a script in your package.json, and want to run a format-on-save feature; configuring the same in your IDE is the way to go.  And if you're not using VSCode, you might be losing out on one of the best IDEs for devs.

Comment: Well, VSCode isn't and IDE, if you really want to bring that up. It's a text editor. I have and use WebStorm, an actual IDE. Regardless, this isn't the behaviour I want.

Comment: You can always make VScode an IDE by adding the build tools that Webstorm has for your project. But since you don't want the behavior I suggested, I guess you could ignore this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is little too late for the answer but since some CRA version you can extend "standard" eslint configuration with `EXTEND_ESLINT` environment variable. You can read about it in [official docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config) and in [this tutorial](https://gaya.pizza/articles/extending-cra-eslint-airbnb/).

Linter configured this way is running with dev server.

Comment: Well that doesn't really have anything to do with the question at all. This is about running the linter while running dev server, not about customizing the linter.

Comment: Linter configured this way is running with dev server also.

Comment: Nothing about that configuration has anything to do about running with the dev server. If it now does that, the change came from CRA.